# html agility pack 10

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack, selectnodes

How can I extract the email address using HtmlAgilityPack in this HTML code :

```
<p class="email">
    <a class="email" href="mailto:babaie@irandoc.ac.ir">
        babaie@irandoc.ac.ir
        <script type="text/javascript">
```

I tried this code (that answered in my last question) but it doesn't work for email :

```
var a = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//a[@class='email']");
if (a != null)
{
    string href = a.Attributes["href"].Value;
    string email = href.Replace("mailto:", "");

    ClassBase.ENonQuery(
        "addfullvalueemail", 
        System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure, new SqlParameter[] {
            new SqlParameter("@Email", email),                 
        });
    }
```

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: Firstly, your HTML example contains only an email address, no website URL. Secondly the hanging comma from your `SqlParameter[]` declaration will cause a syntax error.

Comment: forgot about that code. How can I find that email from this HTML code ? any suggestion ? I wanna catch the email from the sample html. do you know any way ? please help me.